# How to view history of various commands in Emacs

Tags: emacs, elisp

Commands entered after pressing <kbd>M-x</kbd> can be viewed using the <kbd>up</kbd>/<kbd>down</kbd> arrow keys.

How can I get a list of *all* the commands including menu bar invocation, commands
triggered using mouse clicks, etc. in Emacs?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I've used [mwe-log-commands](http://www.foldr.org/%7Emichaelw/emacs/mwe-log-commands.el) to make screencasts.  It shows events and the commands they trigger as you work in Emacs.

---

## [command-log-mode](https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode)

[image: screen shot]

I've just forked it and made it into a proper minor-mode and global-minor-mode along with some other improvements as *[command-log-mode](https://github.com/lewang/command-log-mode)*.

Give it a shot and file issues against me if the documentation is unclear or if you find any bugs.

Comment: I know you're not supposed to write this type of comment but I can't help it: thank you for being a living example of what makes open source so great.

Answer (score 27):

For a complete list of history, type <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>l</kbd> (lowercase "L").

Note: this list is complete in the sense that it keeps all events and commands that happened recently, but it's not complete in the sense that it only keeps track of the last 300 or so events (and corresponding commands).

Comment: He wanted mouse clicks, menu selection, "etc" as well, and C-h l will show these.

Comment: The title is pretty clear:  `command history`.  Event history does not show commands.

Comment: i would also like to see the command that is triggered by the event

Comment: @Tom: in older Emacsen, `C-h l` only showed events, but it has since been improved to also show the commands triggered in response to those events.

Answer (score 2):

So you want the history of of all commands, regardless of where they are executed? I don't know if emacs provides this by default, but you can add your own function to `post-command-hook` which is executed after every command, so you can use it to collect all the executed commands.

Answer (score 0):

`M-x view-lossage`

From emacs documentation

> `(view-lossage)`
>
> Display last few input keystrokes and the commands run. For
> convenience this uses the same format as `edit-last-kbd-macro`. See
> `lossage-size` to update the number of recorded keystrokes.
>
> To record all your input, use `open-dribble-file`.

> `(open-dribble-file FILE)`
>
> Start writing input events to a dribble file called `FILE`. Any
> previously open dribble file will be closed first.  If `FILE` is nil,
> just close the dribble file, if any. If the file is still open when
> Emacs exits, it will be closed then.
>
> The events written to the file include keyboard and mouse input
> events, but not events from executing keyboard macros.  The events are
> written to the dribble file immediately without line buffering.
>
> Be aware that this records all characters you type! This may include
> sensitive information such as passwords.