# How do I capture all commands typed into an Emacs 24 shell?

Tags: shell, emacs24

start emacs 24

M-x shell

(you will see a command line for shell commands)

```
   ls
   cd ~
   mkdir my-test
   ...
```

These commands are often a lot of important history.

I want to collect a log file of all commands typed into all my shell buffers.
Is there an existing way?  Or do I have to mocklisp my path to a solution?

Comment: You may want to look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602640/how-to-view-the-various-command-history-in-emacs).

Comment: Please enable answering, it's a useful question. Bash for example keeps a history, however commands from inside an Emacs shell are not saved there. They are accessible in variable comint-input-ring.

Comment: devnull!  Thanks for the reference.  I'm testing it.

Comment: devnull!  Thanks for the reference.  I'm testing it. MWE is interesting, but it logs the commands from "emacs" point of view, not "shell" point of view. These events are fascinating, but not what I want.  I see "C-x n    other-window [2 times]
RET     comint-send-input [4 times] 
<down-mouse-1>
     mouse-drag-region"